# Annotate Queryset with logarithm of field value in Django

Tags: python, django, database, orm, annotations

I've researched available django aggregation functions and noticed that logarithm is missing there. So, my question is: how can I use logarithm in annotating the Queryset? I cannot take logarithm after Queryset evaluation, because I need to annotate not exactly with logarithm, but rather with an expression containing it, for example for some models `User` and `Task` I need to annotate `User` with `F('task__cost')` / `Log('task__solved_count')`.

UPD: It'd be great if I could do it without using database-specific functions (for Postgres), but that solution is possible too.

Comment: Why not calculate this at *Python/Django* level. We can simply fetch the necessary field, and perform the calculation, this will typically have no *significant* impact on performance.

Comment: In the `dev`branch, these have already been added https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/functions/math/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has these functions, these have been added in [pull request 9622 [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/pull/9622). In the development branch, these already exist under `django.db.models.functions.math` module. But not in the [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1) release. A page is available in the Django dev documentation that [lists the source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/functions/math/).

It turns out that this function is on [most popular database systems the same [Django ticket]](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28643). You can add the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/functions/math.py#L121):

> ```
> from django.db.models import (
>     DecimalField, FloatField, Func, IntegerField, Transform,
> )
> from django.db.models.functions import Cast
>
> # ...
>
> class DecimalInputMixin:
>
>     def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection, **extra_context):
>         # Cast FloatField to DecimalField as PostgreSQL doesn't support the
>         # following function signatures:
>         # - LOG(double, double)
>         # - MOD(double, double)
>         output_field = DecimalField(decimal_places=sys.float_info.dig, max_digits=1000)
>         clone = self.copy()
>         clone.set_source_expressions([
>             Cast(expression, output_field) if isinstance(expression.output_field, FloatField)
>             else expression for expression in self.get_source_expressions()
>         ])
>         return clone.as_sql(compiler, connection, **extra_context)
>
> class OutputFieldMixin:
>
>     def _resolve_output_field(self):
>         has_decimals = any(isinstance(s.output_field, DecimalField) for s in self.get_source_expressions())
>         return DecimalField() if has_decimals else FloatField()
>
> # ...
>
> class Log(DecimalInputMixin, OutputFieldMixin, Func):
>     function = 'LOG'
>     arity = 2
>
>     def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection, **extra_context):
>         if not getattr(connection.ops, 'spatialite', False):
>             return self.as_sql(compiler, connection)
>         # This function is usually Log(b, x) returning the logarithm of x to
>         # the base b, but on SpatiaLite it's Log(x, b).
>         clone = self.copy()
>         clone.set_source_expressions(self.get_source_expressions()[::-1])
>         return clone.as_sql(compiler, connection, **extra_context)
> ```

and then import your defined `Log` function, and use it like:

```
User.objects.annotate(cost_solve_ratio=F('task__cost') / Log('task__solved_count'))
```

Comment: Wow, that's great! Waiting for it to be the part of main Django package!